# Notifications not going away?

Tags: bug, notifications

I have a notification that someone commented on one of my questions, and the notification will not go away no matter what. It appears across the whole network, of course. If I click through to go to the page the comment is on (a question posted on SO), the notification is there waiting to take me to the page a second time! It's infinitely recursive!

Kind of a nasty bug actually, very annoying.

Comment: Oh, yeah, probably that.

Comment: Come on, check the front page before posting new question. It's at least the tenth report about the same problem.

Comment: I apologize, Shadow Wizard.